# Postgres Ordering by subquery/multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have four models: Table, Column, Row, Cell. A Cell belongs to a Row and a Column, both of which belong to a Table. The UI of this looks like your typical table view, the values displayed being those of the Cells.

Cells have a value. Each Table also has one Column of type 'key', whose Cell's values are unique.

Columns can be relational-type, meaning their Cell's values reference the Cells in the key Column of a different Table, the linked Table. This way, a relational Cell will actually 'belong to' a Row from the linked Table since key values are unique.

For relational-type Cells, the value used for display isn't the value stored in the Cell (a value from the linked table's key Column). We let the user choose a Column from the linked Table as the 'display column', and those values are the ones used for display in this Table's relational Column.

Normally we order Rows by the plain old Cell values in the Column chosen for ordering. However, when ordering by a relational-type Column, we want to order by their Cell's *display* value. This means for each Row, we need to find the value stored in the relational Cell (a key value from the linked Table), find the corresponding Row from the linked Table whose key Column's Cell matches that value, then find the value of that Row's display Column's Cell, then order by that value.

Some sample values.

Table 1

```
Column 1 (key)  | Column 2
1               | b
2               | a
3               | c
```

Table 2

Column 2 links to Table 1. This means it stores the key values from Table 1, but currently uses the values from Table 1's Column 2 as its display column.

Actual values in Table 2:

```
Column 1 (key)  | Column 2 (relational)
4               | 1
5               | 2
6               | 3
```

What's displayed:

```
Column 1 (key)  | Column 2 (relational)
4               | b
5               | a
6               | c
```

Post ordering, Table 2 should look like:

```
Column 1 (key)  | Column 2 (relational)
5               | a
4               | b
6               | c
```

I will be frank: I have absolutely no idea how to construct this SQL query/subqueries. Any suggestions pointing me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll draw something up.

Answer (score 0):

If I am following correctly, you want a `join` and `order by`:

```
select t2.column1, t1.column2
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.column2 = t1.column1
order by t1.column2
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than this: a column is made up of cells; 'column' is just an abstraction used to represent a grouping of cells, as are rows. Thanks for the suggestion though, going to keep cracking at this.

Comment: @mikeappell . . . This is based on the sample data in your edited question.

Comment: I suppose I simplified the visualization a bit, because representing the data structure of the full table would be prohibitively difficult. Where there's an entry under Table 1/Column 1 of `1`, that's actually a Cell belonging to Column 1 and Row 1 whose value is '1'.